# ERROR running force:org:create: The signup request failed because this organization has reached its active scratch org limit

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

I am getting this error while trying to create a scratch org with salesforce sfdx, but as you can see, I have no active scratch org !

ERROR running force:org:create:  The signup request failed because this organization has reached its active scratch org limit

[image: The signup request failed because this organization has reached its active scratch org limit]

How to create a scratch orgs ?!

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you have reached the maximum limit of scratch orgs. Please delete the existing scratch orgs to create new one.

Please refer salesforce documentation for managing and deleting the existing scratch orgs.

[Manage Scratch Orgs from Dev Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_view_lex.htm)

Comment: I am starting with salesforce with a trial version. Can I Log in to Dev Hub org as the System Administrator or as a user with the Salesforce DX permissions to do the rest ?

Comment: Are you trying to create scratch org from an existing scratch org ?

Comment: No! why you said that? Can you suggest a command I can try ?

Comment: Can you check your org limit using the command `sfdx force:limits:api:display -u aliasName`. The `aliasName` is the alias of your org